# Building an unsupervised learning model to detect suspicious transactions using DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

I am working on building a unsupervised learning model to detect suspicious transactions using DBSCAN. Do I train the model on all data columns (columns like account number, transaction date, transaction details) or only on the ones that I want to detect suspicion in (money withdrawal and deposit columns)?

[This](https://www.kaggle.com/apoorvwatsky/bank-transaction-data) is the data set that I am working on.

Comment: I'd guess you should use the whole data set so that it can learn the underlying representation of the data. But without more info it's hard to answer without actually trying both things / to propose alternative solutions.